# connecting mongodb server via seperate class

Tags: python, mongodb, flask

I am using flask to create simple api. The api simply returns values from mongoDB. Everything works great if i do the connection within same function. I am not doing connection simply at start of file because i am using uwsgi and nginx server on ubuntu. If i do that then there will be a problem of fork.

However, I have to use this connection with other api so thought to make a seperate class for connection and each api will simply call it . I m using this functionality to make codes manageable. However when i try the these codes it always **shows internal server error**. I tried making this function static too , still the error exists.

Note - I have replaced **mongodb address with xxx** as i am using mongodbatlas account here

```
from flask import Flask
from flask import request, jsonify
from flask_pymongo import pymongo
from pymongo import MongoClient
from flask_restful import Resource, Api, reqparse

app = Flask(__name__)
api = Api(app)
#client = MongoClient("xxx") 
#db = client.get_database('restdb')
#records = db.stars


class dbConnect():
    def connect(self):
        client = MongoClient("xxx") 
        db = client.get_database('restdb')
        records = db.stars
        return records


class Order(Resource):

    def get(self):
        #client = MongoClient("xxx") 
        #db = client.get_database('restdb')
        #records = db.stars
        #star = records
        star = dbConnect.connect
        output = []
        for s in star.find():
            output.append({'name' : s['name'], 'distance' : s['distance']})
        return jsonify({'result' : output})


api.add_resource(Order, '/')


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0')
```

ERROR **`{"message": "Internal Server Error"}`**

Comment: Can you post what error you are getting in the server while firing your Api ?

Comment: @Tony I have edited original post with ERROR at the bottom now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Preliminary investigation suggests that you haven't instantiated your `dbConnect` class. Also, you haven't called the method `connect` properly.

```
class Order(Resource):

    def get(self):
        db = dbConnect() # This was missing
        star = db.connect() # This is how you make method call properly.
        output = []
        for s in star.find():
            output.append({'name' : s['name'], 'distance' : s['distance']})
        return jsonify({'result' : output})
```

Also `class dbConnect()` should be declared as `class dbConnect:`.

Comment: Thank you for spotting syntax mistakes